# Add nodes where touches began

Tags: swift, xcode, nodes, touchesbegan

I´m making a game with Swift.
I need to add nodes where I press the screen, I know this is not from other planet but I can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly simplified example could look like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = SKNode()
    node.position = location
    addChild(node)
}
```

Comment: Actually it works but I can only add one node, when I press two times I get an error. The console says: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: cool, an exception would be a very strange behavior with this code:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add an remove labels by tapping:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController{
        private var labels = [UILabel]()
        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            guard let touch = touches.first else {
                return
            }
            for label in labels {
                if label.frame.contains(touch.location(in: view)) {
                    label.removeFromSuperview()
                    return
                }
            }
            let label = UILabel()
            view.addSubview(label)
            labels.append(label)
            label.text = "touch"
            label.sizeToFit()
            label.center = touch.location(in: view)
        }
    }
```